# Just compiled AOSP, do I need AVD to run 'emulator'?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

Besides `source build.envsetup.sh`, `lunch` and `make`, do I need to manually create AVD before I run `emulator`?  Or is appropriate AVD something emulator takes care of?

[The official guide](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#setting-up-a-linux-build-environment) doesn't hint anything about creating AVD, but going just by those instructions all I get is emulator with generic skin and blank screen. (`emulator -list-avds` shows empty list)

UPDATE: The answer I accepted does not address my exact situation but it fits the actual question I posted. Sadly aosp_deb-userdebug or even -eng don't seem to work with emulator. But that's to be solved in a new/separate question.

Comment: what was your lunch commnad ?

Comment: lunch aosp_deb-userdebug

Comment: You need to run the command `emulator` in the same terminal where the built was done. Otherwise, before running this command, you need to run `source build/envsetup.sh` and `lunch aosp_arm-eng` commands (here I use aosp_arm-eng target).

Comment: I understand that, that is how I do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow are the commands that successfully ran in my machine. Hope it may help you solving the issue.

```
$ export USE_CCACHE=1
$ ccache -M 10G
$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ set_stuff_for_environment
$ lunch full-eng
$ make -j16
$ emulator
```

to get the system.img to rebuild, you need to remove the following files/directories:

```
out/target/product/generic/obj/PACKAGING/
out/target/product/generic/system.img
```

Then simply repeat:

```
$ make -j16
$ emulator
```

Comment: This is how I do it, except I select aosp_deb-userdebug, but that should be okay as I aim for Nexus 7 [2013] (Mobile), i.e. "deb"... I am re-running the whole thing again as of now, I shall copy-paste your sequence of commands just to be sure, will get back to you sir, thank you very much

Comment: Well, full-eng works. It is not the target I need but you made me try it and the emulator works with it, so that's the answer I guess. Wouldn't you know why aosp_deb-userdebug or even -eng wouldn't work with emulator like this? (I did supply their respective vendor binaries.)

Comment: Do you need proprietary binaries to run aosp on the emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AVD, just run the `emulator` command and wait.
The emulator code itself already exist inside the AOSP.

Comment: I tried that, assuming maybe it's just extremely slow. I waited for tens of minutes. :( Do you have any AVDs that maybe get auto-detected by emulator? Does your emulator -list-avds show any please?